# Template field type - Control

Tags: configuration, sitecore-client

I have created a custom field type and it's working good.

Here is the screenshot of how its looks in core database. All i filled in for template field type Template is Assembly and Class fields.

[image]

Here is the screenshot of sitecore's default date field type.

[image]

Like you see the difference, i am not using "Control" field for my custom field type and sitecore default field is not using Assembly and Class fields.

So, my questions are

- what's the use of "Control" Field?
- How sitecore default date field  working with out "Assembly" and "Class" fields?

Comment: The *Control* field specifies the interface that will be exposed to the user.  In your case, it should be the date picker.  Not sure what you mean by "working without Assembly and class".  It might just be storing the value entered in date format.  Not sure what you mean by "How it's working in background".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Sitecore configuration you can find `<controlSources>` section. It contains all the namespaces Sitecore parses when it looks for `content:ClassName` in a field definition (like `Date` in your example).

That's why Sitecore finds `Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Date` class and uses it for the `DateTime` field.

One good example of how this can be extended is in `Sitecore.Buckets.config`:

```
<controlSources>
  <source mode="on" prefix="contentExtension" namespace="Sitecore.Buckets.FieldTypes" assembly="Sitecore.Buckets" />
  <source mode="on" namespace="Sitecore.Buckets.Controls" assembly="Sitecore.Buckets"/>
</controlSources>
```

`prefix="contentExtension"` part says that field definition will have another prefix instead of the default `content`. So if you check `Multlilist with Search` field, you will see there `contentExtension:BucketList` value of the `Control` field.